# CUDA kernel does not modify value

Tags: c++, cuda

Lately I've been getting weird errors connected to my CUDA kernels. To get to the root of that, I wrote this very simple code for testing:

```
#include <iostream>

#define N 3

__global__ void add(int *a, int *b, int *c) {
    int i = blockIdx.x;
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

int main() {
    int *a, *b, *c;
    // I know I could make normal arrays, but at this point I was trying everything to catch the error
    a = new int[N];
    b = new int[N];
    c = new int[N];
    
    int *ca, *cb, *cc;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&ca, N*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&cb, N*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&cc, N*sizeof(int));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        a[i] = 1;
        b[i] = 2;
        c[i] = 5;
    }
    
    cudaMemcpy(ca, a, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(cb, b, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(cc, c, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    
    add<<<1, N>>>(ca, cb, cc);
    
    cudaMemcpy(a, ca, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(b, cb, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(c, cc, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        std::cout << "c[" << i << "] = " << c[i] << std::endl;

    cudaFree(ca);
    cudaFree(cb);
    cudaFree(cc);
    
    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    delete[] c; 
    return 0;
}
```

Now, it should override the value of 5 in the array `C`, but my output shows it is still 5 by the end. I have been trying to change the values and the code itself, but the result is the same. I have a feeling that the error is not coming from the code, but somehow from CUDA itself. Should I try reinstalling it or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: In the add, why do you use `blockIdx.x` instead of `threadIdx.x`?, you allocate one block of N threads, so you wand ever thread to operate on a single item, but when the all opreate on the `blockIdx.x`th item, only one item will be changed. Though i would expect the first item to change from 5 to 3

Comment: Good catch, however the result is still the same. Originally it was `add<<<N, 1>>>`, but changed it out of frustration

Comment: Not repro (`blockIdx` is replaced by `threadIdx`); most likely case is that there is some error in the kernel call. Try calling [`cudaGetLastError()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__ERROR.html#group__CUDART__ERROR_1g3529f94cb530a83a76613616782bd233) immediately after the kernel call to check for errors.

Comment: Thank you @kakkoko, I did not know about this function, and I managed to catch the error with it. Looks like my CUDA installation was messed up, the kernel code couldn't run, so back to reinstalling it :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my CUDA installation *was* messed up, it was using a version, that was not supported by the driver, causing the kernel to not run. Bit annoying that without the `cudaGetLastError()` it did not show me any problems, but at least I know how to check for these kind of errors.

Thanks again @kakkoko for pointing it out!

Comment: See [What is the canonical way to check for errors using the CUDA runtime API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14038589/10107454). The reason why one needs `cudaGetLastError()` is described in the documentation [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#error-checking).